# How to get start year from count of year in php?

Tags: php, yii2

I have save year as input into database but it save the duration like if I get input 1990 as input in database save 26.Here 26 is difference of current date to selected date 2016-1990=26.I am using php Date function but it's not work proper.Using this get fixed year 1970

```
<?php
        $dr = [];
        for($i = date("Y"); $i > date("Y") - 100; $i--) {
            $dr[] = $i;
        }
        echo $form->field($model, 'ven_established_date')->dropDownList($dr);//Here Select year 
       ?>
    $date = $model->ven_established_date;
                echo '$date'.$date;
                $year = date("Y", strtotime($date));
                echo '$year'.$year;
```

Comment: You're getting `1970` as year because `strtotime($date)` returns `0`. What's the output of `var_dump(strtotime($date));`?

Comment: after var_dump(strtotime($date)) i got a bool(false)

Comment: Is there a valid date inside `$date`?

Comment: what is your date format?

Comment: I have select year as input from drop down list

Comment: I don't have any idea how to convert duration count into year..please tell me how to do this

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. It is very unclear. What is your current output and what is your desired output?

Comment: What is the out put of this statement : echo '$date'.$date; ? . Then we can see whether $date has value or not?

Comment: you want to do someting like `$input = '1993';
   
  $duration = date('Y') - $input;`

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not much clear so what i understood from your question is you have a year count(ex:-26) and you want exact year.
Solution:-

```
$yearCount = 26; //input you have, getted from DB
$currentYear = date("Y");
$pastYear = $currentYear - $yearCount;
echo $pastYear;
```

Comment: yet not save proper year into database duration is save instead of year...I with attach my code where I have select year

Comment: As per your code you are creating normal array and passing in dropdown list,Instead of that you should pass assosiative array.So your array creating code should be :- 
$dr = [];
        for($i = date("Y"); $i > date("Y") - 100; $i--) {
            $dr[$i] = $i;
        }